# How to execute hql file in spark with arguments

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a hql file which accepts several arguments and I then in stand alone spark application, I am calling this hql script to create a dataframe.

This is a sample hql code from my script:

```
select id , name, age, country , created_date
from ${db1}.${table1} a 
inner join ${db2}.${table2} b
on a.id = b.id
```

And in this is how I am calling it in my Spark script:

```
import scala.io.Source
val queryFile = `path/to/my/file`
val db1 = 'cust_db'
val db2 = 'cust_db2'
val table1 = 'customer'
val table2 = 'products'
val query = Source.fromFile(queryFile).mkString
val df = spark.sql(query)
```

When I am using this way, I am getting:
`org.apache.spark.sql.catylyst.parser.ParserException`

Is there a way to pass arguments directly to my hql file and then create a df out of the hive code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can be injected with such code:

```
val parametersMap = Map("db1" -> db1, "db2" -> db2, "table1" -> table1, "table2" -> table2)
val injectedQuery = parametersMap.foldLeft(query)((acc, cur) => acc.replace("${" + cur._1 + "}", cur._2))
```